# How do I answer this question? I get stuck after differentiation. (LOCAL MAX/ MIN HELP)

Tags: calculus

[The Math Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7PXf.jpg)

I have issues with finding the Local Max and Min, and Abs Max and Min, after I find the Critical Point. How do I do this problem in its entirety?

Comment: Unfortunately your photo is cut off at the top, so we cannot tell if the function is $\sqrt{x}\ln(8x)$ or $\sqrt{x\ln(8x)}$. You should also tell us what work you have done so far or what thoughts you have and where you get stuck.

Comment: The function is the former .

Comment: Also all ive done is differentiate and find a critical point. Im stumped on what to do next

Comment: Okay, that's part (a). Next it says to use the first derivative test to determine whether the critical points you found were local minima or maxima. Do you know the first derivative test?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For first derivative test let $x=a$ be the critical point, if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f^{'}(x) \text{ is positive and } \lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f^{'}(x)\text{ is negative then a is Local maxima} $$

and

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f^{'}(x) \text{ is negative and } \lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f^{'}(x)\text{ is positive then a is Local minima} $$

Otherwise, you are looking at an inflection point.

Hope it solves your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
f'(x)=\dfrac{\ln(8x)}{2\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{\ln(8x)+2}{2\sqrt{x}}
$$
it is clear that $f$ is decreasing on $(0,e^{-2}/8)$, and increasing on $(e^{-2}/8,\infty)$. In particular $f$ has an absolute minimum at $e^{-2}/8$. The absolute minimum value is
$$
f(e^{-2}/8)=-e^{-1}/\sqrt{2}
$$